# RadioButton draggable only move radio button circle not value Why?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my dilemma...

I want to make movable radiobutton with its value but its only move radiobutton circle not its value.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" id="tstrdb" value="radiobuttion1" name="1">radiobuttion1</input>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$("#tstrdb").draggable({cancel:''});
```

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/464hqka5/)**

This is working with **DIV** tag.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divtag"><input type="radio" id="tstrdb" value="radiobuttion1" name="1">radiobuttion1</input></div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(".divtag").draggable();
```

**[DIV DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/464hqka5/1/)**

But i don't want to add more controls.

Is there any other way where i do without DIV tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<input>` Tags cant be closed. If you want to label an input tag, use `<label>`:

```
<label id="test"><input type="radio"/> Your label</label>
```

then call:

```
$("#test").draggable()
```

In opposite to a wrapping `<div>`, `<label>` ensures you can click on the label to change the radiobox.

Comment: The above pretty much answers everything. `input` elements are [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements), thus having no closing tag and no content. More importantly, the code in this answer is **valid markup**, unlike `<input>...</input>`.